# Register com dll made in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, com

I'm working on DLL responsible for sending request to wsdl service by SOAP protocol and getting response which contains information about a company. I’ve managed to create VB.NET function, which does it and I got com dll. After that I used regasm to add reference to registry about that dll. After that I tested it in form application (Borland delphi) and it worked. Now I have to make it work on other users computers. I suppose I need to make some type of script making reference in registry to that DLL, but what is efficent way to do that considering (If im not wrong) that regasm is visual studio tool only. I read about set up packages in visual studio but i want to make sure it is the way to go before deep diving into it.

Comment: No, regasm is a framework tool.  It is gacutil.exe that won't be available, the tool that registers the assembly in the GAC.  Pretty important on the user's machine given the DLL Hell trouble that is associated with COM.  In general you always want an installer for COM components, it is usually all you got when you they call for support five+ years from now.  They will call.

Answer (score 2):

Regasm doesn't come with Visual Studio, but with the .NET Framework itself. So you can find it in paths like

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
```

to register your dll in the 32-bit part of the registry and

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
```

to register your dll in the 64-bit part of the registry.

If you build your dll as "Any Cpu", you can register it for both 32 and 64 bit part of the registry.